# Mocking "with open()"

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, with-statement

I am trying to unit test a method that reads the lines from a file and process it.

```
with open([file_name], 'r') as file_list:
    for line in file_list:
        # Do stuff
```

I tried several ways described on another questions but none of them seems to work for this case. I don't quite understand how python uses the file object as an iterable on the lines, it internally use file_list.readlines() ?

This way didn't work:

```
    with mock.patch('[module_name].open') as mocked_open: # also tried with __builtin__ instead of module_name
        mocked_open.return_value = 'line1\nline2'
```

I got an

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Maybe because the with statement have this special attribute to close the file?

This code makes file_list a MagicMock. How do I store data on this MagicMock to iterate over it ?

```
with mock.patch("__builtin__.open", mock.mock_open(read_data="data")) as mock_file:
```

Best regards

Comment: The phrase `for x in y:` creates an iterator via the call `iter(y)` which will try to call `y.__iter__()` to create it.  So I propose to intercept this call via a mock.

Comment: `read_data` *is* the data you'll iterate over.

Comment: This may be a case, though, where you want to modify your code to make it easier to test. Assuming this is a function that takes a file name as an argument, have it take a file *object* instead. This makes the caller responsible for opening the file, but it also lets you pass a `StringIO` object as the argument for testing. (As a general rule, pushing I/O as far to the edges of your code as possible makes it easier to test.)

Comment: @chepner I think read_data is only applied to file_obj.read() method using this method got me back the read_data. Because in this code it never enter the for loop probably because it is trying to iterate over the MagicMock and it does't work.

Comment: @chepner The refactoring is a very good advice thanks!

Comment: @Alfe It makes sense. However I have no idea how to intercept and mock the .__iter__() method so it can iterate over some data on the MagicMock Object. Do you have any example or reference for that ?

Comment: Looking at the docs for `mock_open`, it looks like support for `__iter__` was not added until Python 3.7. (Which seems like a *huge* oversight to me, but better late than never, I guess.)

Comment: That's good to know (It really seems like an oversight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `mock_open` (until Python 3.7.1) doesn't provide a working `__iter__` method, which may make it unsuitable for testing code that iterates over an open file object.

Instead, I recommend refactoring your code to take an already opened file-like object. That is, instead of

```
def some_method(file_name):
    with open([file_name], 'r') as file_list:
        for line in file_list:
            # Do stuff

...

 some_method(file_name)
```

write it as

```
def some_method(file_obj):
    for line in file_obj:
        # Do stuff

...

with open(file_name, 'r') as file_obj:
    some_method(file_obj)
```

This turns a function that has to perform IO into a pure(r) function that simply iterates over *any* file-like object. To test it, you don't need to mock `open` or hit the file system in any way; just create a `StringIO` object to use as the argument:

```
def test_it(self):
    f = StringIO.StringIO("line1\nline2\n")
    some_method(f)
```

---

(If you still feel the need to write and test a wrapper like

```
def some_wrapper(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_obj:
        some_method(file_obj)
```

note that you don't need the mocked open to do anything in particular. You test `some_method` separately, so the only thing you need to do to test `some_wrapper` is verify that the return value of `open` is passed to `some_method`. `open`, in this case, can be a plain old mock with no special behavior.)